# How do I determine if a StartExecution limit has been reached

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-step-functions

I am currently running a state machine via AWS Step Functions and we have had a lot of traffic. I noticed that the StartExecution API request as a limit of 100 in a bucket and 2 per second refill. However, I cannot seem to determine from any of the CloudWatch metrics if this throttle limit has ever been reached. Based on the sheer volume we may have reached it but I would prefer to see a count or list of throttled API requests.

Is there any clear way to get this data?

Answer (score 1):

From the CloudWatch metrics http://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/procedure-cw-metrics.html you will get a general idea of your StartExecution API rate. However, you can’t know how many APIs are throttled from the CloudWatch metrics. When your API is getting throttled, you will receive a “ThrottlingException” error message on your side and you can save these error messages in a log or database. With both CloudWatch metrics and saved ThrottlingException messages, you will know how many percent of your API requests are throttled. Based on that, you can send a request to AWS support engineer to increase the API limit for you. Note that the API limit is a soft limit and can be increased.

As a reference, this is the default limit page: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/limits.html

Hope this helps!